# I Need this VBA Code to work in Entire Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim SrchStr As String

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("b1", ActiveSheet.Range("b65536").End(xlUp))
    SrchStr = Range("k1")
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Cool story, bro. So, what's your actual problem? Please re-read [ask] for tips on improving this question so that maybe someone will assist you. And then *edit* your question appropriately.

Comment: Research how to loop through sheets. You can use something like `For Each ws in Worksheets` where `ws` is a declared variable (type `Worksheet`)

Comment: What does that mean, to "Work in Entire Workbook". Can you explain what you want this code to do? Do you want to loop through every sheet, test column B for the value in `K1` and delete any row where `K1` value is present. Does K1 change for each sheet, or is it the same `K1` from the `Activesheet` that is searched for in all sheets? Please elaborate as we're not sure what you want.

Comment: I have a workbook of my employees details in which I have 3 different sheets, sheet 1 is of employees personal details, sheets 2 is for employees leave records & sheet 3 is for employees salary payments. Now in each sheet cloumn B is of employees name. So my question is that if any employee leaves can its row be deleted from all worksheets at once because right now i have to manually delete its row from all worksheets. The vba code which i have posted is working only on current sheet and not on all sheets i. e it is deleting row only in sheet where it is applied, i want it for all the sheets.

Comment: @ArpitJain you should add info to your original question, people will not trawl through comments to try to work out your question like it is a puzzle. Read the "how to ask" for tips as pointed out above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set SrchRng = sh.Range("b1", sh.Range("b65536").End(xlUp))
        SrchStr = sh.Range("k1")
        Do
            Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: the code you gave is not working, it not even deleting rows now.

Comment: I just added a for each loop to your code, nothing else. For me it's working ;-) I assume the original code was not written by you, right?

Comment: Yes i didn't t wrote that, i did some research and found it on the internet. Can you explain me how to make it work?

Comment: For me it's working. Just writing "the code you gave is not working" does not give any clue what might be wrong. Possibly `SrchStr` is only on the first sheet in `K1` but how should I know.

Comment: @ Storax I do not know vba so i can not tell, have you tried running?

Comment: Yes, I tried my code. I told you: For me it's running. If you do not know vba at all and if you just want to get code you are probably in the wrong place.

Comment: How come this, same code running in your system and not on mine, doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does make sense if you'd be able to read the code and would set the preconditons like having a value in K1 on every sheet. But if you have a different request then the code will not do what you want.